# making a todo list using pickle and flask

Tags: python, flask, pickle

i'm trying to make a simple todo list using flask and a text file database, for now I'm trying to add items and save it in a text file, and also show the items online, but I'm not sure what I'm going wrong,this is the code i have for now

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import todo_list

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():


    with open('programming.pkl', 'rb') as output:
        new_list = todo_list.pickle.load(output)

          
    return render_template('index.html', todo1=new_list, todo=todo  )

@app.route('/task', methods=['GET''POST'])
def task():
    if  request.method == 'POST':
        todo = request.form.get('todo')

    with open('programming.pkl', 'wb+') as output:
        todo_list.pickle.dump(todo, output)

    return redirect('/')
```

and this is my HTML code, i have just used google.com as a place holder for now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
  <head>
    <h1> TODO APP</h1>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>        
            <br>
            <h2>Here are your todo items</h2>
        </p>
        <br>
            <h3>{{ todo }}</h3>
            <h4><a href = "www.google.com">Mark as done</a></h4>
            <br>
            <h3>{{ todo }}</h3>         
            <h4><a href = "www.google.com">Mark as done</a></h4>
            <br>
            <h3>stuff1</h3>
            <h4><a href = "www.google.com">Mark as done</a></h4>
            <br>
            <form action="/task" method="POST">
                <h3>Create todo</h3>
                <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo"><br><br> 
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This will give you an idea: https://github.com/ninjakx/TODO-app

Comment: what is `todo` in `render_template('index.html', todo1=new_list, todo=todo  )` it should be `return render_template('index.html',  todo=new_list  )`

Comment: @Pygirl but still when i add a task in my text box - it redirects me into a page that says file not found